# What is the "__v" field in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `Mongoose` version 3 with `MongoDB` version 2.2. I've noticed a `__v` field has started appearing in my `MongoDB` documents. Is it something to do with versioning? How is it used?

Comment: if you don't want it in the result use _doc on the returned object form mongoose

Answer (score 420, accepted):

From [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey):

> The `versionKey` is a property set on each document when first created
>   by Mongoose. This keys value contains the internal revision of the
>   document. The name of this document property is configurable. The
>   default is `__v`.
>
> If this conflicts with your application you can configure as such:

```
new Schema({..}, { versionKey: '_somethingElse' })
```

Comment: Is it safe to use this property to determine if a document was just created (e.g. `__v === 0`)?

Comment: @ExplosionPills for future reference: no. The version key is only incremented after operations that could cause a conflict, modifying array positions. Other updates won't increment it. The original release post explains it in detail: http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning

Comment: Is there a way to hide it from the returned docs from the queries?

Comment: @diosney `query.select('-__v')`.  @ExplosionPills you would need to add mongoose middleware like `schema.pre('save', function (next) { this.increment(); next(); })`.

Comment: @diosney You could use the transform option of Document.toObject() to delete the __v property. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: **@talentedmrjones** **@wprl** That is exactly what I'm doing now, but I wanted something that I could put in the Schema directly so in **all** queries.

Comment: Also if you don't want it you can set: ```new Schema({..}, { versionKey: false }) ```

Comment: Why does it works with array only ? Why not with other fields ?

Answer (score 109):

Well, I can't see Tony's solution...so I have to handle it myself...

---

If you don't need version_key, you can just:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nickname: String,
    reg_time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, {
    versionKey: false // You should be aware of the outcome after set to false
});
```

Setting the versionKey to false means the document is no longer versioned.

This is problematic if the document contains an array of subdocuments. One of the subdocuments could be deleted, reducing the size of the array. Later on, another operation could access the subdocument in the array at it's original position.

Since the array is now smaller, it may accidentally access the wrong subdocument in the array.

The versionKey solves this by associating the document with the a versionKey, used by mongoose internally to make sure it accesses the right collection version.

More information can be found at: http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.com/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html

Comment: what is the outcome of setting it to false?

Comment: You can also call `resultFromMongo.toObject({ versionKey: false })`, to surppress the value.

Comment: @xperator the outcome is no __V field in the scheme:
{   
    "_id": { "$oid": "5aa62e99f36d28237f1a41ad" }, 
    "email": "scott@gmail.com", 
    "sessions": 0 
} 
vs 
{ 
    "_id":{ "$oid": "5aa62e99f36d28237f1a41ad" }, 
    "email": "scott@gmail.com", 
    "sessions": 0,
    "__v": 0 
}

Comment: or this `schema.set('versionKey', false);`

Comment: what's the out come after setting to false? other than it not being in the document?

Answer (score 17):

For remove in NestJS need to add option to `Schema()` decorator

```
@Schema({ versionKey: false })
```

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to disable the version key if you don't need it.

See this example:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
   FullName:{
       type :String,
      
   },
   BirthDay:{
       type :String,
       
   },
   Address:{
       type :String,
   },
   Gender:{
       type:String,
   },
   PhoneNumber:{
       type:Number,
       ref:'Account'
   },
   AccountID:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account'
   },
   UserName:{
       type:String,
       ref:'Account'
   }
},{collection:'User',
   versionKey: false //here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the version key.It gets updated whenever a new update is made. I personally don't like to disable it .

Read this solution if you want to know more
[1]: [Mongoose versioning: when is it safe to disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810637/mongoose-versioning-when-is-it-safe-to-disable-it)

Answer (score 4):

the '__v' field in our 'document' serves '**optimisticConcurrency'** concerns.

This term basically means in mongoose :
let, you grabed a document by 'findOne, findById' but **not** used save() method of mongoose yet. and what if at this interval, any other code grabed same document and used .save() method before the first document instance.
at this use case, if we want to (mongoose specific) throw a version error kinda thing, we use `optimisticConcurrency: true` option in schema.

**and then mongoose will use '__v1' to compare these two document.**

without `optimisticConcurrency: true` option. '__v' has no has no effect. and mongoose will not increase it by 1.

Note : in 'findOneAndUpdate' kinda operations, will not update '__v'. (only save() updates)

Answer (score 3):

`__v` is commonly known as version key.
When you create a new document in a collection, its version `key(__v)` is `0`. The version `key(__v)` of that particular document changes to `1` when you update it for the first time. This increment continues as soon as you continue updating this document.
For example:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    age: 37,
    __v: 0
  }
After updating:
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    age: 40,
    __v: 1
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `__v` field is called the version key. It describes the internal revision of a document. This `__v` field is used to track the revisions of a document. By default, its value is zero (`__v:0`).

If you don't want to use this version key you can use the `versionKey: false` as `mongoose.Schema` parameter.

You can follow this example...

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },

        password: {
            type: String,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false, // Here You have to add.
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('tbl_user', userSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use **versionKey: false** in Schema definition

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export class Account extends mongoose.Schema {

    constructor(manager) {

        var trans = {
            tran_date: Date,
            particulars: String,
            debit: Number,
            credit: Number,
            balance: Number
        }

        super({
            account_number: Number,
            account_name: String,
            ifsc_code: String,
            password: String,
            currency: String,
            balance: Number,
            beneficiaries: Array,
            transaction: [trans]
        }, {
            versionKey: false // set to false then it wont create in mongodb
        });

        this.pre('remove', function(next) {
            manager
                .getModel(BENEFICIARY_MODEL)
                .remove({
                    _id: {
                        $in: this.beneficiaries
                    }
                })
                .exec();
            next();
        });
    }

}
```