# Mongoose __v property - hide?

Tags: mongoose

Mongoose adds a '__v' property into Schema's for versioning - is it possible to disable this globally or globally hide it from all queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "\_\_v" field in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495891/what-is-the-v-field-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can disable the "__v" attribute in your Schema definitions by setting the `versionKey` option to `false`. For example:

```
var widgetSchema = new Schema({ ... attributes ... }, { versionKey: false });
```

I don't think you can globally disable them, but can only do it per Schema. You can read more about Schema's [options here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey). You might also find the [Schema set method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-set) helpful.

Comment: is it safe to disable "__v" attribute? will it cause any future issue if I disable it?

Comment: Is there a way to hide it from the returned docs from queries?

Comment: Is it safe?  You can read the details [here](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning).  TL:DR; Mongoose uses the version key to help avoid errors encountered by positional notation e.g. `$set: { 'comments.3.body': updatedText }`.  If you read a document and use that update statement but someone modifies the `comments` array in the meantime you could update the wrong comment.  With a version key you will get an exception in that case.

Answer (score 64):

To disable '__v' property, which is not recommended, use the [`versionKey` schema option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey):

```
var Schema = new Schema({...}, { versionKey: false });
```

To hide it from all queries, which sometimes can be [not what you want too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025570/2153350), use the [`select` schema type option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select):

```
var Schema = new Schema({ __v: { type: Number, select: false}})
```

Comment: So how can I delete _id and __v before returning them to user? Is there any kind of mapping I can do? Mapping from schema to model would remove these two attributes and mapping from model to schema would let's say remove some fields user should not be able to edit but still see them.

Answer (score 33):

Two ways:

1. `{versionKey: false}`
2. when you query, like `model.findById(id).select('-__v')`

`'-'` means exclude the field

Answer (score 24):

define a `toObject.transform` function, and make sure you always call `toObject` when getting documents from mongoose.

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
    <some schema spec>
  } , {
    toObject: {
      transform: function (doc, ret, game) {
        delete ret.__v;
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you can call `user.toObject({ versionKey: false })`, which will hide `__v` version property.

Comment: Do you also need `toJSON()`?

Comment: @binki No, not needed

Answer (score 8):

Try this it will remove _v from every query response.

```
// transform for sending as json
function omitPrivate(doc, obj) {
    delete obj.__v;
    return obj;
}

// schema options
var options = {
    toJSON: {
        transform: omitPrivate
    }
};
// schema
var Schema = new Schema({...}, options);
```

Answer (score 6):

You may not want to disable `__v`, other answers provide few links to answer why you shouldn't disable it.

I've used this library to hide the `__v` and `_id`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-hidden

```
let mongooseHidden = require("mongoose-hidden")();

// This will add `id` in toJSON
yourSchema.set("toJSON", {
        virtuals: true,
    });

// This will remove `_id` and `__v` 
yourSchema.plugin(mongooseHidden);
```

Now `__v` will exist, but it won't be returned with `doc.toJSON()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why use a library to do this silly simple transformation ? refer toJSON or toObject schema option instead. toObject() worked for me.

Comment: You're right. Other answers have recommended the same thing. @NIKHILCM

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Query Middleware to exclude any field from the output. In your case you can use this:

```
// '/^find/' is a regex that matches queries that start with find
// like find, findOne, findOneAndDelete, findOneAndRemove, findOneAndUpdate
schema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
    // this keyword refers to the current query
    // select method excludes or includes fields using + and -
    this.select("-__v");
    next();
});
```

For more information in docs lookup:
[Middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)
[select method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

Answer (score 0):

set this after connected to DB (server.js)

```
mongoose.modelNames().forEach(function (modelName) {
    mongoose.model(modelName).schema.set("versionKey", false);
});
```

Comment: doesnt work. still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

For devs who are using nestJS

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection

```
@Schema({
  versionKey: false, // this will prevent adding the __v when new record is created.
})
export class Cat {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  breed: string;

  @Prop({ select: false }) // this will hide the __v when you do a select/find query
  __v: number;
}
```

Answer (score -23):

Yes, it is simple, just edit the "schema.js" file that is inside

`"node_modules\mongoose\lib"`

Search for `"options = utils.options ({ ... versionKey: '__v'..."` and change value `"__v"` to `false`.

This will change all post requests. `(versionKey: '__v' => versionKey: false)`

Comment: This is terrible advice.

Comment: You should not change code inside `node_modules`. The content of this folder changes often with npm install and it should be added to `.gitignore`. Whatever you write there will be lost.