# Mongoose.js except _id & __v from query result by default

Tags: mongoose

I can except a field from query results declaring it like:

field: {type: 'string', select: false}

Is but it possible to do that with _id and __v field?
I tried

_id: {select: false}

But It seems not to work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this as long as you also include the `type` of the field in the schema definitions:

```js
_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, select: false},
__v: {type: Number, select: false},
```

However, that's going to prevent Mongoose from being able to find your model instance (and update its `__v`) on a `save` unless you explicitly *include* those fields in your `find`.  So make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: when use _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, select: false }, it works. It seems mongoosejs change the definition: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html