# .insertOne is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to preface this by saying I have read several posts here regarding this issue.

I have a node/express/mongo app with the following:

app.js:

```
    var express = require('express')
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var cors = require('cors')
    var morgan = require('morgan')
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    var passport = require('passport')

    var app = express()

    // MongoDB Setup
    var configDB = require('./config/database.js')
    mongoose.connect(configDB.url)

    app.use(morgan('combined'))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    // Check security with this
    app.use(cors())
     // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

    require('./routes')(app)
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)
    console.log('We are up and running, captain.')
```

routes.js

```
const AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/AuthenticationController')

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register)
}
```

My mongo schema file Account.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

var accountSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  likesPerDay: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 250 },
  followPerDay: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 250 },
  unfollowPerDay: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 250 },
  commentsPerDay: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 250 },
  comment: String,
  hashtags: [String]
})

// methods ======================
// generating a hash. We hash password within user model, before it saves to DB.
accountSchema.methods.generateHash = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null)
}

// checking if password is valid
accountSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password)
}

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema)
```

And finally my controller file AuthenticationController.js

```
const Account = require('../models/Account.js')
// var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

module.exports = {
  register (req, res) {
    Account.findOne({email: req.body.id}, function (err, account) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Could not regster user')
        throw err
      }
      if (account) {
        console.log('account already exists')
      } else {
        Account.insertOne({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('could not insert')
            throw err
          }
          console.log('inserted account')
          Account.close()
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I am getting an error in my **AuthenticationController** file when I call `Account.insertOne` function.

I get the error that

> TypeError: Account.insertOne is not a function

Now several of the posts here on stack have advised that I make sure that I am exporting the model from my model class, which I am doing, and that would fix this issue. Its weird because the `findOne` method seems to be fine, but when I call the `insertOne` i get an issue.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A Mongoose model doesn't have an `insertOne` method. Use the [`create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) method instead:

```
Account.create({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, function (err, doc) {
```

Comment: I was previously using `updateOne` with `upsert`, and I noticed that `create` will create a key called `__v`. How do I disable this?

Comment: @AaronFranke Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699784/mongoose-v-property-hide Better late than never

Answer (score 8):

[The Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) show how to create documents:

Either via **`Account.create()`**:

```
Account.create({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, function (err, res) {
    // ...
})
```

Or by **instantiating and `save()`ing** the account:

```
new Account({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}).save(function (err, res) {
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

as of [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), try using

```
Account.create({ ...params ... }, function (err, small) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`insertOne` command is not available in mongoose directly as mentioned in [Mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html). If you want to use `insertOne` command then you need to use bulk command in order to send this command to MongoDB server. Something like below. I hope this works.

```
Account.bulkWrite([
  {
    insertOne: {
      document: {email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}
    }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `create()` instead of `insertOne()`.

https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/using-insertone-in-mongoose