# db.collection.insertOne not working, is there something wwrong with my code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Ok, so here's some context. Basically, i'm making a discord bot and im using mongoose to store user data, like how much gold they have in their bank, but I've tried looking at tutorials and copying code(we're all guilty of it) but nothing seems to work.
Here's my code:

```
const user = db.collection.insertOne({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            guild: msg.guild.id,
            gold: 0,
        })
```

Comment: what's your collection name? you sure it's "collection"?

Comment: no but when i use the name of the collection it still doesn't work. @Rukshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with mongodb command

```
db.collection.insert({...})
```

You can check it out  [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)

OR

with mongoose

```
myModel.create({...})
```

You can check it out [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create)

Answer (score 1):

insertOne is not available in mongoose

try reading more on this this answer of stackoverflow :  [insertOne is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692306/insertone-is-not-a-function)