# I cannot post document in mu mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Insertone method is not working

Whenever I try creating a new document into the database I get this error:

```
MongooseError: Operation `products.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Pafun\server1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.jgowihc.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.jgowihc.mongodb.net'
}
```

Comment: There is no `insertOne` in mongoose. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46692499/21972629)

Comment: That error message says it is the DNS lookup timing out: `querySrv ETIMEOUT`.  See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903530/2282634

Comment: thank you all I added google dns '8.8.8.8' to my wifi settings , now its working