# Mongoose versioning: when is it safe to disable it?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey):

> The versionKey is a property set on each document when first created
>   by Mongoose. This keys value contains the internal revision of the
>   document. The name of this document property is configurable. The
>   default is __v. If this conflicts with your application you can
>   configure as such:
>
> [...]
>
> Document versioning can also be disabled by setting the versionKey to
>   false. DO NOT disable versioning unless you know what you are doing.

But I'm curious, in which cases it should be safe to disable this feature?

Comment: This blog post talks about the case where you access elements in subdocument array positionally. But mongoose in fact uses ids instead of positions. So I am not sure either:
http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The version key purpose is optimistic locking.

When enabled, the version value is atomically incremented whenever a document is updated.

This allow your application code to test if changes have been made between a fetch (bringing in version key 42 for example) and a consequent update (ensuring version value still is 42).
If version key has a different value (eg. 43 because an update has been made to the document), your application code can handle the concurrent modification.

The very same concept is often used in relational databases instead of pessimistic locking that can bring horrible performance. All decent ORMs provide such a feature. For example it's nicely described [in ObjectDB documentation](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock#Optimistic_Locking_). It's an object database implemented in Java but the same concept applies.

The [blog post](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning) linked in Behlül's comment demonstrate the optimistic locking usefulness with a concrete example, but only for arrays changes, see below.

On the opposite, here is a simple case where its useless: a user profile that can be edited by its owner ownly. Here you can get rid of optimistic locking and assume that the last edit always wins.

So, only you know if your application need optimistic locking or not. Use case by use case.

The Mongoose situation is somewhat special.

Optimistic locking is enabled only for arrays because the internal storage format uses positional index. This is the issue described by the [blog post](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning) linked in the question's comment. I found the [explanation](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongoose-orm/137g5v9qs7/mongoose-confusion-about-versioning) given in the `mongoose-orm` mailing list pretty clear: if you need optimistic locking for other fields, you need to handle it yourself.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bpceee/c6acb6c86f5674b91eba) showing how to implement a retry strategy for an `add` operation. Again, how you want to handle it depends on your use cases but it should be enough to get you started.

I hope this clears things up.

Cheers

Comment: Do we need versioning if we are using `$in` operator to reach to subdocuments. It doesn't seem different than accessing to the parent document to me.

Comment: Once again, it depends on the use case. When using the $in operator, you tighten the concurrent modification window but remember that it's still open.

Comment: @esKotos I think Your new updated answer looks ambiguous because versioning not work when we only update any non array field.

Comment: @esKotos Apart from that What if  I'm not modifying an array field and want to achieve this feature?

Comment: @SandeepSharma you need to call document.increment(), before any save(). This will give the signal to increment version, in case of save success (validation ok and no version conflict)