# Mongo not returning document even though it exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

so I went into the mongo shell `./mongo` and did the following commands:

```
>>>use mydb
>>>show collections
myc
myotherc
users

>>>db.myc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8dd1c7b350e73a6bc7cf50"), "name" : "mfirst", "theowner" : ObjectId("5c8d7146bc279c28a6ded7b2"), "mowner" : ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc"), "created" : ISODate("2019-03-17T04:49:11.194Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8dd4dfb547843bdee5b9bd"), "name" : "mlast", "theowner" : ObjectId("5c8d7146bc279c28a6ded7b2"), "mowner" : ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc"), "created" : ISODate("2019-03-17T05:02:23.723Z"), "__v" : 0 }

>>>db.myotherc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc"), "people" : [ ObjectId("5c8d7146bc279c28a6ded7b2") ], "name" : "thename", "owner" : ObjectId("5c8d7146bc279c28a6ded7b2"), "created" : ISODate("2019-03-17T04:21:14.388Z"), "__v" : 0 }

>>>db.myc.find({"mowner._id":"5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc"})

>>>db.myc.find({"mowner.name":"thename"})
```

Both the last two queries return nothing, even though I think I have the syntax correct and it does exist. Any idea why?

Comment: If you are using mongoose, as the tags say, you want to populate the fields with the object ids
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051977/what-does-populate-in-mongoose-mean

Comment: Your query should be `db.myc.find({"mowner": Objectid("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc")})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet doesn't work on my end. (returns nothing still)

Comment: I misspelled the ObjectId. Try it again. It should work

Comment: @HarisBouchlis I feel like it should still return something. `populate` just populates a field. My query should still return the object `myc` (without `mowner` populated). Right? I tried though with populate but still returns nothing.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I tried it with the fix. Still doesn't work. I doing it from within the shell `./mongo` but it doesn't work with mongoose too.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
db.myc.find({"name":"thename"})
db.myc.find({"mowner": ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc")})
```

Answer (score 0):

> db.myc.find()
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5c8dd1c7b350e73a6bc7cf50"), "name" : "mfirst",
> "theowner" : ObjectId("5c8d7146bc279c28a6ded7b2"), "mowner" :
> ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc"), "created" :
> ISODate("2019-03-17T04:49:11.194Z"), "__v" : 0 }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5c8dd4dfb547843bdee5b9bd"), "name" : "mlast", "theowner" :
> ObjectId("5c8d7146bc279c28a6ded7b2"), "mowner" :
> ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc"), "created" :
> ISODate("2019-03-17T05:02:23.723Z"), "__v" : 0 }

In `myc collection`,`mowner` and `name` both are the flat fields to the collection. Therfore you need to change the query to :-

```
db.myc.find({"name":"thename"})
db.myc.find({"mowner": ObjectId("5c8dcb3a7f1b20386577d4bc")})
```