# How can I get a specific key value from another schema, By comparing if they have same key value?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have Node.js app, served by express, I got two different mongoose schema userModel and postMode, with my frontend being made with React.js. I'm creating a component that will create and display posts. Display post will contain username, avatar, date, text, and images. The problem is the avatar is in the userModel. Is there a way that I can also display the avatar from another schema? I'm thinking that I will compare the two schema based on if they have the same key value because both of them have username. To display the post I send Axios to get request based on the postModel.

```
Backend
export const getUserRelatedPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const postData = await postModel.find({});
  res.json(postData);
});
```

Schema
postModel
[image]

userModel

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but in looking at the two schemas you shared, the values in the username element don't match.

Comment: I think the better way is to embedded  user data  in your post or create a ref (then populate) to UserModel. when you create new post That way you can limit number of request you made.

Comment: @ScottGnile I apologize but it should be johndoe for both usernames. The output that I want is I want to get the avatar value from userModel by so i can use that on my post Component but the problem is the postModel is the one that i'm using on the post component.

Comment: @VoQuocThang Sir, can  you give me some links on how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @rjc30 here is the populate approach : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051977/what-does-populate-in-mongoose-mean

Comment: Thank you so much @VoQuocThang

Answer (score 1):

You could use mongoose's populate feature

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

In your postModel add a virtual 'user' element

```
const postSchema = Schema({
    //your existing postModel definition

});

postSchema.virtual('user', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: 'username',
    foreignField: 'username',
    justOne: true
});
```

I am assuming your userModel exports User something like this:

```
const userSchema = Schema({
    //your existing userModel definition
})

const User = model('User', userSchema);
```

Then in you express route you ought to be able to do something like this:

```
export const getUserRelatedPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const postData = await postModel.find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'user',
            select: 'avatarPhoto'
        });
    //you should be able to access the avatar photo(s) like this
    console.log(postData.map(u => u.user.avatarPhoto)

    res.json(postData);
});
```

Comment: This assumes that the values in username in both models are the same

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm having an issue if I used the .find the avatarPhoto is undefined but if I used .findOne it will work.

Comment: That is correct, find returns an array, not a single record... my bad.

Comment: Yap, I'm still searching for a solution to this problem. thanks for your help!