# Can anyone explain me about the populate method in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose-schema, populate, mongoose-populate

I have started learning about MERN stack as well I am doing a project for better understanding but there's a use of populate method and the mongoose documentation is little confusing for me to understand that particular topic. So is there anyone who have good knowledge of Mongoose populate method and can explain me in deep with clear definition and examples. Please it's my humble request that explain like you are explaining a beginner.
THANK YOU❣️

I have asked peoples out there to explain me about populate method.

Comment: This is not what StackOverflow is for.  `populate` is similar to the SQL `JOIN` concept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does populate in mongoose mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051977/what-does-populate-in-mongoose-mean)